# How to make BuildConfigField value dynamic in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

I want to make HostName field dynamic. so I can have different HostName for both app1 and app2, for develop and release

```
**app1 {
        dimension "client"
        applicationId = "com.app1.random"
    }
    app2 {
        dimension "client"
        applicationId = "com.app2.random"
    }
    develop {
        dimension "environment"
        buildConfigField "String", "HOSTNAME", "\"https://app1.example.com\""
    }
    release {
        dimension "environment"
        buildConfigField "String", "HOSTNAME", "\"https://app1.com\""
    }**
```

Comment: This above code is already in  productFlavors{ }

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you

```
 flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors{
        develop {
        buildConfigField "String", "HOSTNAME", "\"https://app1.example.com\""
        }

        release {
        buildConfigField "String", "HOSTNAME", "\"https://app1.com\""
        }
    }
```